# Getting error "The folder is already a source folder" when linking source in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse, I am wanting to link an external source folder into my current project. To do so, I did the following steps:

1. With the project open, go to the menu bar and choose Project -> Properties
2. On the left side, choose "Java Build Path"
3. In the source tab, click "Link Source..."
4. Navigate to the other source folder (e.g. "OtherLocation/src")

However, whenever I do this, I get the following error in the link source folder window:

> The folder is already a source folder.

I'm really not sure what to make of this. I know that it is a source folder, that's why I'm trying to link to it!

What is the real meaning of this error message and how can I go about resolving it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the error is referring not to the folder that you pointed to, but rather the name that you are giving it in Eclipse:

[image]

What the error message is really saying is that the project already has a folder called "src". You are currently telling the linked folder to appear in the project as another folder called "src", which would create a conflict. Just change the second field to something else and it will work.

In other words, it is not an issue with the name of the directory (there is no need to change that), it's just that you are giving it a name within Eclipse that matches the name of something that already exists in your project.